# If Java has no Preprocessor what is "import"

Tags: java, language-features

This [article](http://java.sun.com/docs/white/langenv/Simple.doc2.html) says No More Typedefs, Defines, or Preprocessor in 2.2.1 . In C++ the `include` is part of the preprocessor. What is the `import`?

Comment: It's worth noting that the more similar keyword in C++ is `using`.

Comment: @Bringer128 `using` is part of C# not C++. In C/C++ the word is `#include "..."` or `include <...>` :)

Comment: I was referring to [this keyword](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fusing_directive.htm)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Import despite the name doesn't "import" anything, it just let you call the classes without the fully qualified name.

To clarify, if I do an `import java.util.ArrayList;`, now I can refer to `ArrayList` class as just `ArrayList`. If I don't do it, I can still use the class, I just have to call it `java.util.ArrayList`.

If you import whole packages with `*`, the worst thing it can happen is that there is a name clash, thus, you've to use the full name to refer to a Java class, but it doesn't use more memory at runtime.

Classes in `java.lang` are automatically "imported".

Java 1.5 introduced [static imports](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html), which enables programmers to refer to imported static members as if they were declared in the class that uses them. They should be used sparingly. An acceptable use is for importing JUnit Assert methods. For instance, with a traditional import:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
...
Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
```

With static import:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
...
assertEquals(expected, actual);
```

Answer (score 2):

Import allows you to use an unqualified class name. For instance, with `import java.util.ArrayList` you can use an unqualified type name `ArrayList` in your code. Without the import statement, you would have to always use the fully qualified name: `java.util.ArrayList`.

There's also static import, which brings static class elements into the name space of the compilation unit.

Answer (score 1):

`import` makes package names known within the file where it is used. It is not at all comparable to C's `#inlclude`.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the rigid source code naming convention, the Java compiler can easily find the corresponding source or class files just from the *fully qualified name of a package and class*. By fully qualified name I mean specifying the full package and class e.g.

```
java.util.ArrayList x = new java.util.ArrayList ();
```

The alternative to this long-winded style of coding, is to use import statements.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
ArrayList x = new java.util.ArrayList();
```

Also it is a great help to understanding someone else’s code

Answer (score 0):

A way to tell the compiler you are using some class from another package?

EDIT: [link to the spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html#7.5)